# Endeca Experience Manager Query

Tags: endeca

I am using Endeca experience manager. I need to filter the results in the Endeca query for the dimensions.

I need to apply both OR operation in the Endeca queries for the dimensions.

Given a sample query to understand my requirement.

http://www.example.com/endeca_jspref/controller.jsp?sid=1463DDBF22F0&enePort=16000&eneHost=hostname&N=0&Ntk=brand.name|product.color&Ntt=canon+kodak|red+blue&Ntx=mode+matchany

The Search of canon and kodak against the dimension brand.name and red , blue against the dimension product.color. My  requirement is to apply OR condition that matches any of the four conditions and give the results.

I need the OR condition query.

Kindly suggest!

Thanks.

Comment: I need the below operation: AND(OR(brand.name: kodak,canon) prod.color: red)

Comment: Are you confusing Experience Manager with the Reference Application (JSPREF)?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to read through the `Record Filters` in the [Advanced Development Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28910_01/MDEX.622/pdf/AdvDevGuide.pdf).

If you are trying to use a Record Filter on a property, you will need to enable it explicitly in Developer Studio for that property, while your Dimensions will automatically have the ability to apply a Record Filter. This will help when you have explicit values to filter on, for example `brand.name`.

Your query should then look something like this:

```
Nr=AND(OR(brand.name:kodak,brand.name:canon),prod.color:red)
```

Try this in your JSP Reference App first to make sure you have it all working.

Comment: Yeah thanks radimpe. I have checked this and working fine. I need to explore a search with in search functionality.I need to use something like this Ntk=All|test&Ntt=camera|shoe* where camera needs to be searched against All interface and shoe needs to be searched against test interface and bring the type ahead. Is it possible to apply AND condition in the parameter Ntt? Please let me know if I am not clear.

Comment: So is the question really: "How can I invoke typeahead (for shoe*) on a filtered (for camera) resultset?"

Comment: Yeah. In the search term type ahead(2nd time search) it should bring the new values based on the first keyword search should be matched.

Comment: FYI the first search is made against a search interface all which contains properties and dimensions. For the second time, I need to bring the results for the typeahed that should match the first term also like AND condition.

Comment: Hi Radimpe, I have saw your answer in the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20247189/endeca-search-query-on-multiple-fields. I need something like this. Ntk=empName|empId&Ntt=s*|1234* . Hope you understand.

Comment: I'm not sure that will work. You may be able to apply a navigation filter to your search and then apply the type-ahead on top of that but to do a keyword search against the 'All' interface and then a typeahead against a separate interface seems unlikely. I've definitely not come across such a usecase.

Comment: Is it possible to do wildcard search against the dimensions? for example:Nr=AND(OR(brand.name:kodak,brand.name:canon),prod.color:red)&Ntt=s* should bring all the results matching my filter condition in the Nr parameter. I have enabled wildcard search in the dimensions. I am getting the response if i type the complete word shoe. Can i get the same using Ntt=s*. I am not using the search interface since I cannot use that in the record filter Nr.

Answer (score 0):

This will require some custom coding.

In a custom cartridge add a DimensionSelectorEditor and a BoostBuryEditor where the DimensionSelectorEditor drives the values in the BoostBuryEditor.  To keep from creating a custom editor use just the Boost section of the editor to get the dimension values.

Code below shows the editors in the template.

```
<editors:DimensionSelectorEditor
    propertyName="dimensionName" idProperty="dimensionId" label="Dimension Name"
    enabled="true" />
<editors:BoostBuryEditor propertyName="dimensionValues"
    boostProperty="featuredOneBoost" buryProperty="featuredOneBury"
    label="Filter By Boost - First Dimension Choice"
    dimensionIdProperty="dimensionId" enabled="true" />
```

In the supporting java handler code for the template pull those values and add them to the existing record filters for the current navigation state as an OR in the preprocess method.

Key sample code below:

```
getNavigationState().getUrlFilterState().getRecordFilters().add(FilterUtils.or(new PropertyConstraint(dimensionName, dimensionValue)));
```